# How to use a single result from an API as a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm working on my first react project and I'm trying to use API data to create a surf report for my local beach.

I've managed to fetch the API data and display all of the results as a list on the page but what I really want to do is use the latest ( or second latest because direction seems to be wrong on the latest ) result data in a variable.

Also do I need to fetch the whole list if I want to filter the data as I have mentioned above or can I request just the bit I need somehow?

Here's the fetch -

```html
// Waves //

const WAPI = 'https://data.qld.gov.au/api/action/datastore_search?limit=400&resource_id=2bbef99e-9974-49b9-a316-57402b00609c&q=Mooloolaba';

class WApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      records: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(WAPI)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ records: data.result.records }));
  }

  renderRecords = () => this.state.records.map(record =>
      <li key={record._id}>
        {record.Hsig} m
        {record.Direction} direction -
        {record.DateTime}
      </li>
  );

  render() {
    const { records } = this.state;

    return (
      <ul>
        {!records.length ? <p>Loading...</p> : this.renderRecords() }
      </ul>
    );
  }

}
```

Here's an example of where I'll be using the data

```html
const waveDirection = 149.1;

const direction =
  wDirection > 0 && waveDirection <= 5 ? 'North' : 'Other';
```

Comment: If you are only interested in the last two results do `this.state.records.slice(-2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also do I need to fetch the whole list if I want to filter the data as
>   I have mentioned above or can I request just the bit I need somehow?

Depends on the API you're using, some API's will allow you to specify params and request certain bits of information. But if not, you will need to request all the data, then filter it. You should cache the data you get from the API if you're looking to filter it.

To access the last 2 results you could just use `this.state.records.slice(-2)`

Comment: thanks ! this worked well, I managed to grab the second last record by using .slice(-2,-1). I guess the second half of my question is about using the data in this result in my variable rather than render .map() into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Congrats your first React project debut.

I think you can solve that problem in two ways.
1. requesting the backend api returns the latest one. I don't know about that api in details so I can't confirm it support such thing but I think that will be the normal and general method.
2. Sorting and getting the results from frontend side.

```
let latestRecord = data.result.records.sort(
      (a, b) => moment(b.DateTime) - moment(a.DateTime)
    )[0];
```

Regards,